# Ruby on rails, PATCH method reverted by transaction rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm not good at ruby but I have to make a project using rails and I encountered a problem. I'm making a forum application where a user can have multiple profiles and change between them. After many hours I thought that maybe it would be easier if I added a whole column to the Users table called current_profile_id where I'd store the current chosen profile by the user. I am using the PATCH method to insert a profile id into the table but upon doing that the transaction gets rolled back and I am left with nothing. I am a total newbie and kinda don't want to do this so my code is most likely terrible.

view:

```
  <% @user.profiles.each do |profile| %>
    <%= link_to content_tag(:div, profile.name), users_profiles_path(:current_profile_id => profile.id), method: :patch %>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= current_user.current_profile_id %>
  </div>
```

user controller:

```
def setProfile
 @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
 @user.current_profile_id = params[:current_profile_id]
 @user.save
end
```

route:

```
  patch '/users/:id/profiles', to: 'users#setProfile'
```

[screenshot from wsl teminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39e1T.png)

I know the idea isn't really thought through but at this point I kind of have to roll with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your patch request per se: it's that you don't have a view template set up for the controller to forward to. Try creating view template to go with your `setProfile` action, or redirect the request to another location from that action.

Comment: I added a blank view "setProfile.html.erb" and it still gets rolled back.

Comment: The save function was running validations for current user's password and other stuff. I made it skip it and it works now. :)
Thank you a lot anyways! Happy New Year's.